# c++, binary number calculations

Tags: c++, binary

I have question that asks how values such as c are computed in terms of binary numbers. Im researching it but now but figured id ask here if anyone has somewhere they can send me or explain how this works.

```
int main()
{
int a 10, int b = 12, int c, int d;

int c = a << 2; //output 40
}
```

Comment: Look up bitwise shifts. Answering this would just be doing your homework.

Comment: Is there a particular line, command, or expression that is not covered in your exercise book? Or do you want us to start with explaining what `int` does on the first line, continuing one symbol at a time?

Comment: This doesn't work (won't even compile). `<<` is defined in terms of multiplying by a power of two though, so `x << 2` is the same as `x * 4`.

Comment: thanks for the direction, reading up on bitwise shifts was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not answering with C++ code, as the question is not really related to the language.

The integer ten is written 10 in **base 10** as it's equal to 1 * 10^1 + 0 * 10^0.
Binary is **base 2**, so let's try to write ten as a sum of powers of 2.

10 = 8 + 2
That is 2^3 + 2^1.
Let's switch to binary (using only two digits : 0 and 1).
2^3 is written 1000
2^1 is written 10
Their sum is 1010 in binary.

"**<<**" is the operation that shift left binary digits by a certain amount (beware of overflow).
So 1010 << 2 is 101000
That is in decimal 2^5 + 2^3 = 32 + 8 = 40

You can also think of "<< N" as being a multiplication by 2^N of an integer.